# Converting string to date in R returns NAs

Tags: r, date, na

I have a column of my dataframe as

```
 date
17-Feb
17-Mar
16-Dec
16-Nov
16-Sep
17-Feb
```

I am trying to convert it into a `date` column from `string`. I am using the following pieces of code:

```
 as.Date(df$Date, format="%y-%b")
```

and

```
 as.POSIXct(df$Date, format="%y-%b")
```

Both of them give `NA`s

I am getting the format from  [this link](https://www.statmethods.net/input/dates.html)

The starting number is year. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: your data are %d-%b, but you are trying to convert with %y-%b. Just switch the two.

Comment: Sorry that is 2017 not 17

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume from your approach that the 17 and 16 refer to the year 2017 and 2016 respectively. You need to also specify the day of month. If you don't care about it, then set it to the 1st.

A slight modification to your code will work, by appending '-01' to the date then updating your `format` argument to reflect this:

```
df = data.frame(Date = c("17-Feb", "17-Mar", "16-Dec"))
as.Date(paste0(df$Date, "-01"), format="%y-%b-%d")
```